# Use of extern in C++ dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static, extern

I declare then instantiate a static variable in a DLL.

```
// DLL.h
class A
{
    //...
};

static A* a;



// DLL.cpp
A* a = new A;
```

So far, so good... I was suggested to use `extern` rather than `static`.

```
extern A* a; // in DLL.h
```

No problem with that but the `extern` variable must be declared somewhere. I got *Invalid storage class member*.

In other words, what I was used to do is to declare a variable in a source file like this:

```
// In src.cpp
A a;
```

then `extern` declare it in another source file in the same project:

```
// In src2.cpp
extern A a;
```

so it is the same object *a* at link time. Maybe it is not the right thing to do?

So, where to declare the variable that is now extern?

Note that *I used static declaration in order to see the variable instantiated as soon as the dll is loaded*.

Note that the current use of `static` works most of the time but I think I observe a delay or something like this in the variable instantiation while it should always be instantiated at load time. I'm investigating this problem for a week now and I can't find no solution.

Comment: Either way this is a horrible and unsafe way to do singletons. Use a private static variable and a function to access it. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern (And I've never seen sane usage of `extern` in C++)

Comment: Well, actually, it is *realy* not the way I do singletons... But We had to code that way for a particular purpose. Anyway, I thing my problem won't be solved with such questions. It is probably much more complex than what I can explain here. Thanks anyway.